# How to resolve MemoryError: memory allocation failed with Micropython?

Tags: python, memory-management, micropython

Im working with a SiPy board from pycom for a proyect, and all goes well untill i implemented 2 new files (that doesn't modify proyect behavior itself), but after uploading new files and trying to run my code, it shows a `MemoryError: Memory allocation failed, allocating 136 bytes`.

i tried a `os.fsformat("/flash")` to clean the board and upload again the proyect but i ended up with the same error. I also tried to workaround the "error line" (just an import of another class that worked well) doesn't solve it, just found the same error later, in another import with different bytes allocated.

Comment: How can this behaviour be replicated?

Comment: I checked device info and, despite i have enough flash memory space, it seems the RAM or "Memory status" in device info is filled, 4MB/4MB, so i guess any board with filled RAM will tell the same error, i'd like to know how to clean RAM memory because it seems a problem in runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the micropython port you are working with you could consider using:

```python
import micropython

micropython.alloc_emergency_exception_buf(100)
```

early in the `boot.py` file?

Answer (score 1):

If you have enough RAM on the target device, you might want to enlarge the heap size that is being used by `micropython`.

To check the memory data of `micropython`:

```
$ micropython
>>> import micropython
>>> micropython.mem_info()
mem: total=3818, current=728, peak=1592
stack: 464 out of 40000
GC: total: 1024512, used: 816, free: 1023696
 No. of 1-blocks: 13, 2-blocks: 7, max blk sz: 8, max free sz: 63971
```

The important part in my example is `free: 1023696`. So I could, for example, run `micropython` with 2MB heap memory available. To do this, use the following options:

```
$ micropython -X heapsize=2M
>>> import micropython
>>> micropython.mem_info()
mem: total=2620, current=542, peak=1406
stack: 464 out of 40000
GC: total: 2049088, used: 592, free: 2048496
 No. of 1-blocks: 8, 2-blocks: 6, max blk sz: 8, max free sz: 128019
```